# Add code to TFS using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have code on my local machine and want to put that into TFS. I have a new folder in TFS and I've mapped my TFS workspace to the local folder. How can I add code from my local machine to TFS?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the solution and select `Add to source control...`. It will then ask you to choose where you want to put it into TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder where the code file need to be uploaded You will get these options and then select on + Add File. It will give you two options either to create new file or to upload existing file[image]